# How to create a bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, char

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ140.png)

suppose student has many projects and wants to upload that projects on web(system).
Now system wants to track or keep records of number of projects of that particular student.
Now system gives entire details about the projects of student(user)
like when project was uploaded, which day and month.
This data will be shown in the form of chart (like bubble chart).

There are three parameters

```
1) Y-axis 
include week day's only. days will be constant. It'll not change irrespective of data (like input).


2) X-axis 
include months only. months will be constant.It'll not change irrespective of data (like input).

3) Z-axis
include data from database.Data could be anything like number of projects(only digits).
```

Suppose I'm a student(user) and I upload project on Monday in the month of Jan.
Then on bubble chart it should display number of projects I have uploaded on which days of the week and month.

It is similar to GitHub chart where it gives all the details about the of user activities.

I have no idea from where to start.
I have tried various libraries for charts like chart.js,highchart.js....

I have tried this.
https://jsfiddle.net/h0Lm1jgz/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Heat Map</title>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script>
      Highcharts.chart('container', 
      {

            chart: {
                type: 'heatmap',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 80,
                plotBorderWidth: 1
            },


            title: {
                text: 'Project Details'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
            },

            yAxis: {
                categories: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
                title: null
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                layout: 'vertical',
                margin: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                symbolHeight: 280
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ' ' +
                        this.point.value + '</b> projecys uploaded on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                }
            },

            series: [{

                borderWidth: 1,
                data:   [
                            [0, 0, 10], 
                            [0, 1, 19], 
                            [0, 2, 8], 
                            [0, 3, 24], 
                            [0, 4, 67], 
                            [1, 0, 92], 
                            [1, 6, 58], 
                            [1, 2, 78], 
                            [1, 3, 117], 
                            [1, 4, 48], 
                            [2, 0, 35], 
                            [2, 1, 15], 
                            [2, 2, 123], 
                            [2, 3, 64], 
                            [2, 4, 52], 
                            [3, 0, 72], 
                            [3, 1, 132], 
                            [3, 2, 114], 
                            [3, 3, 19], 
                            [3, 4, 16], 
                            [4, 0, 38], 
                            [4, 1, 5], 
                            [4, 2, 8], 
                            [4, 3, 117], 
                            [4, 4, 115], 
                            [5, 0, 88], 
                            [5, 1, 32], 
                            [5, 2, 12], 
                            [5, 3, 6], 
                            [5, 4, 120], 
                            [6, 0, 13], 
                            [6, 1, 44], 
                            [6, 2, 88], 
                            [6, 3, 98], 
                            [6, 4, 96], 
                            [7, 0, 31], 
                            [7, 1, 1], 
                            [7, 2, 82], 
                            [7, 3, 32], 
                            [7, 4, 30], 
                            [8, 0, 85], 
                            [8, 1, 97], 
                            [8, 2, 123], 
                            [8, 3, 64], 
                            [10, 4, 84], 
                            [9, 0, 47], 
                            [9, 1, 114], 
                            [9, 2, 31], 
                            [9, 3, 48], 
                            [11, 4, 91]],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }]

    }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try to use Highcharts heatmap series type. Check these examples: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas

Comment: Thanks a tonn. I was looking for this. You saved my day.

Comment: How can I add on-click event..? Like if I click on a particular project then it should display details about the project like                          
"Project_Name was upload on July 25, 2019".                                         I have modified it (https://jsfiddle.net/h0Lm1jgz/) I tried adding on click event and tried to show project details.

Comment: You can add click event like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lkcfg36x/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click

Comment: I'm so grateful for your help. I have never used charts before in my projects. You saved lot of my time. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code

```
             <!-- highcharts library -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="heap_map_chart" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card border-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;" id="moreInfo">

        </div>
    </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    requestData();
    function requestData()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/profile/heap_map_data',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) 
            {

                console.log(response);
                var chart_data = [];
                var count = 0;
                for(var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++)
                {
                    date_value = response[i].event_start_date;
                    var d = new Date(date_value);   
                    var year = d.getFullYear();
                    var month = d.getMonth();
                    var day = d.getDay();
                    var actualDay = day -1;

                    chart_data.push([month,actualDay,response[i].user_id]);

                }
                console.log("chart_data ==",chart_data);


                Highcharts.chart('heap_map_chart', 
                {

                        chart: {
                            type: 'heatmap',
                            marginTop: 40,
                            marginBottom: 80,
                            plotBorderWidth: 1,

                        },


                        title: {
                            text: 'Project Details'
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            categories: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
                            title: null
                        },



                        colorAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                        },

                        legend: {
                            align: 'right',
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            margin: 0,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 25,
                            symbolHeight: 280
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () 
                            {
                                return  + this.point.value + ' <b> project was uploaded on ' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ' date, 2019' + '<br /> click to view more' ;
                            }
                        },

                        plotOptions: 
                        {
                                series: 
                                {
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    point: 
                                    {
                                        events: 
                                        {
                                            click: function () 
                                            {

                                                var year = 2019;
                                                var month = this.x;
                                                var y_axis_day = this.y;

                                                $.ajax(
                                                    {
                                                        url: '/profile/heap_map_event_details',
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        data: {year:year,month:month},
                                                        success: function (response) 
                                                        {

                                                                var $message_list= document.getElementById("moreInfo");
                                                                $message_list.innerHTML = '';
                                                                for(var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++)
                                                                {

                                                                    var date = new Date(response[i].event_start_date);   
                                                                    var day = date.getDay();
                                                                    var actualDay = day -1;
                                                                    actualDay = Number(actualDay)

                                                                    if(y_axis_day == actualDay)
                                                                    {
                                                                        $message_list.innerHTML = $message_list.innerHTML + `<div class="card online_user" ><li class="list-group-item link-class" style="cursor: pointer;"> <div class="d-flex bd-highlight"> <div class="img_cont"><img src="../public/image/${response[i].e_imagepath}" class="rounded-circle user_img"><span class="online_icon offline"></span> </div><div class="user_info">${response[i].event_name}}<br/><small style="color:#F44336"><strong>${response[i].event_start_date} message</strong></small><br/><small>Last seen <small>${response[i].event_end_date}</small></small></div> </div> </li></div>`;
                                                                    }




                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                                                        {
                                                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                                                            console.log(jqXHR);
                                                            console.log('textStatus:');
                                                            console.log(textStatus);
                                                            console.log('errorThrown:');
                                                            console.log(errorThrown);
                                                            alert(errorThrown);                            
                                                        } 
                                                    });

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                        series: [
                            {

                            data: chart_data,
                            borderWidth: 1,

                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: '#000000'
                            }
                        }]

                }); 


            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
                alert(errorThrown);
            } 

        });
    }

})
    </script>
```

API

```
router.get('/profile/heap_map_data', function(req,res)
{
    console.log("No. of time being called 1")
    const user_id = req.session.user_id;
    Posts.findAll()
    .then((data)=>
    {
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>
    {
        res.send(err);
    })

})

router.post('/profile/heap_map_event_details', function(req,res)
{
    const year = Number(req.body.year);
    var month = Number(req.body.month);
    month = month + 1;
    if(month < 10)
    {
        month = "0"+month;
    }

    Posts.findAll({where:{event_start_date:{[Op.endsWith]:  '%' + "2019-"+month+"-" +'%'}}})
    .then((data)=>
    {
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>
    {
        res.send(err);
    })


})
```